# PRIORVALUE Owner - Manager - Email

Tags: apex, process-builder, winter17

We have a process builder process which is attempting to pass the prior lead owner's manager's email as a parameter to an underlying apex class which uses this value as a "to" email address. Below is the specific function we are trying:

PRIORVALUE([Lead].Owner:User.Manager.Email)

We are receiving a non-descript "flow" error basically indicating this isn't working. However, when we change it directly to just an email string ("test@test.com"), it works fine so the underlying apex appears stable.

Furthermore, we have other "prior values" being passed as parameters for the email which are working fine (PRIORVALUE([Lead].Owner:User.FirstName) is being passed as the email display name and its working fine).

Are we not allowed to go back to the User -> Manager level in a prior value? I believe I'm playing with some Winter '17 functionality here so maybe its just not yet stable. Thanks all.